# Treating values in a list of data frames as one object in r

Tags: r, dataframe, analysis

I am trying to apply various analysis functions (lm, plot, etc.) to a long list of data frames. All of the data frames have the same column headings, and I want to calculate 1 result for all data under each column heading in the data frame. I can't figure out how to use the 'unlist' function in order to do this.

IE for the example below, I would want one plot with n = 15, and one linear model of all $a ~ all $b.

```
d1 <- data.frame(a=rnorm(5), b=1:5, c=rnorm(5))
d2 <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=rnorm(5), c =rnorm(5))
d3 <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=rnorm(5), c= rnorm(1:5))

my_test_data <- list()

my_test_data <- list(d1, d2, d3)
```

I have tried everything, including:

```
plot(unlist(my_test_data), my_test_data$a)

lm(my_test_data$a ~ my_test_data$b, unlist(my_test_data))
```

Let me know what I am missing - all help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `rbind` instead to combine the `data.frame`s?

```
d1 <- data.frame(a=rnorm(5), b=1:5, c=rnorm(5))
d2 <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=rnorm(5), c =rnorm(5))
d3 <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=rnorm(5), c= rnorm(1:5))

my_test_data <- rbind(d1, d2, d3)

m <- lm(a ~ b, data = my_test_data)
plot(a ~ b, data = my_test_data)
abline(m)
```

[image]

Comment: You could expand it to handle an arbitrary number of data frames in a list with `Reduce` or `do.call` on the `rbind`

Comment: Another idea is `data.table::rbindlist`